# Return test answers for each user including users with no answers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables:

```
    users
+-----------+
| id | name |
+-----------+
|  1 | John |
+-----------+
|  2 | Doe  |
+-----------+

    tests
+-----------+
| id | test |
+-----------+
|  1 |  t1  |
+-----------+

         questions
+----+----------+---------+
| id | question | test_id |
+---------------+---------+
|  1 |    q1    |    1    |
+---------------+---------+
|  2 |    q2    |    1    |
+---------------+---------+

                  answers
+----+--------+------------+-------------+
| id | answer | is_correct | question_id |
+----+--------+------------+-------------+
|  1 |    a1    |    1     |      1      |
+---------------+----------+-------------+
|  2 |    a2    |    0     |      1      |
+---------------+----------+-------------+

                        user_answers
+----+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| id | user_id | test_id | question_id | answer_id | duration |
+----+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|  1 |    1    |    1     |      1     |      1    |     1    |
+--------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
|  2 |    1    |    1     |      2     |      2    |     1    |
+--------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

I'm trying to get the name of the user, the correct/incorrect answer and total duration.

The output would look like:

```
+------+-----------+----------+
| name |  correct  | duration |
+------+-----------+----------+
| John | 1,0,1,1,0 |      5   |
+------+-----------+----------+
| Doe  | 0,0,0,0,0 |      0   |
+------+-----------+----------+
```

Or:

```
+------+-----------+----------+
| name |  correct  | duration |
+------+-----------+----------+
| John | 1,0,1,1,0 |     5    |
+------+-----------+----------+
| Doe  |     0     |     0    |
+------+-----------+----------+
```

The SQL query I'm trying with:

```
SELECT u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(a.is_correct, 0)) AS correct, SUM(ua.duration) AS duration 
FROM user_answers ua
RIGHT JOIN users u 
ON u.id = ua.user_id 
RIGHT JOIN answers a 
ON a.question_id = ua.question_id
JOIN questions q
ON q.id = a.question_id
JOIN tests t
ON t.id = q.test_id
WHERE t.id = 1 GROUP BY u.id
```

It's just returning the user who answered the questions. I want to get the other user too who didn't answer the questions

Here is a fiddle with data and the SQL query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a806a/3

Comment: what is your expected output based on this data?

Comment: @Utsav The name of each user from `users` + is_correct from `answers`. If the user didn't answer any question, I would still get his name + 0 for `is_correct`

Answer (score 0):

Start with all possible combinations of users, questions and correct answers. Left join real answers

```
SELECT u.name,  GROUP_CONCAT(case when ua.id is null then 0 else 1 end order by q.id) AS correct 
from questions q
cross join users u 
join answers a on a.question_id = q.id and a.is_correct = 1
left join user_answers ua
   on q.id = ua.question_id 
      and u.id = ua.user_id 
      and ua.answer = a.answer
WHERE q.test_id = 1 
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

Note the `order by q.id` clause. You may want a different ordering.

Returns

```
name    correct
John    0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0
Doe     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: I think it's not working properly. Comparing correct answers for `John` seems incorrect for some of them

Comment: @mm1234,  to get flags in the order, add an  `order by` to `group_concat` as needed. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Yeah. It's working fine now. But one last thing. Please take a look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a806a/2 . I added a new column called `duration` to `user_answers` and inserted 1 for all of them. When I try to get `SUM(ua.duration)` I only get 2. How to get the correct one?

Comment: It would be quite different query. The curent one selects only correct answers as it was required

Comment: I get some other data from these tables. Name and is correct are the main ones. But I need other data too

Answer (score 0):

for quick edit of the existing query, we can join it with the users table
and use case when to set the null record to be like that

```
SELECT users.name, CASE WHEN correction.correct IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE correction.correct END as correct from 
(SELECT u.name,u.id, GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(a.is_correct, 0)) AS correct 
FROM user_answers ua
RIGHT JOIN users u 
ON u.id = ua.user_id 
RIGHT JOIN answers a 
ON a.question_id = ua.question_id
JOIN questions q
ON q.id = a.question_id
JOIN tests t
ON t.id = q.test_id
WHERE t.id = 1 GROUP BY u.id )  correction
right join users on users.id = correction.id
```

fiddle with query
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf4c84/67